# Drawing line in Canvas having issue

Tags: javascript, ios, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm currently working on an iOS app which uses `HTML 5` and `JavaScript` for drawing Graphs.

I just did a sample App.

#### My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            function init()
            {
                var can = document.getElementById('can');
                can.addEventListener("click",click, false);
            }

            function click(event)
            {
                var can = document.getElementById('can');
                var c = can.getContext('2d');
                var parentPosition = getPosition(event.currentTarget);
                c.lineWidth = 1;
                c.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
                c.beginPath();
                c.moveTo(a, b);
                a = event.clientX - parentPosition.x;
                b = event.clientY - parentPosition.y;
                c.lineTo(a, b);
                c.stroke();
            }
            function getPosition(element)
            {
                var xPosition = 0;
                var yPosition = 0;

                while (element)
                {
                    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
                    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
                    element = element.offsetParent;
                }
                return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body oncopy='copy();' onpaste='paste();'onload ='init();'>
            <canvas id="can" style="height:300px;width:300px;background-color:black;">Oops!</canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### My Issue:

When a user Taps on the screen, I'm drawing a line to that particular point from previous point.

But in my case when I tap on the screen the line is drawn to some other point. Say if I tapped on point (100,100) the line will be drawn to (100, some arbitrary value). Always the Y position is wrong.

What I did:

- Tested it on simulator
- Tested it on device
- Tested it on Firefox
- Tested it on Chrome

All results are same. I couldn't find the issue. I alerted the clicked `x` and `y` co-ordinate. It's coming correctly. Only problem is with the draw functionality.

#### Screenshots:

[image: Clicked point]

[image: Drawn Line]

As you can see the X-coordinate is correct. But Y-coordinate is always coming wrong.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please make these changes.

In html line@47,

```
 <canvas id="can" height=300 width=300 style="background-color:red;">Oops!</canvas>
```

In script line@23,

```
            c.beginPath();
            c.moveTo(a, b);
            a = event.clientX - parentPosition.x;
            b = event.clientY - parentPosition.y;
            console.log('a:'+a+'--b:'+b);
            c.lineTo(a, b);
            c.stroke();
```

Comment: @MidhunMP Please, the code it's from the first reply, you DON'T HAVE to change it because it works for a 300x300 canvas and not for others size. I clearly explained why it's "/2" in the **LAST EDIT**

Comment: @MidhunMP I clearly explained how to reuse the code now, this edit it's wrong anyway. He just changed the code as the code you posted on the question. I suggest you, N K, to be sure of what you write before to post it

Comment: @AlessandroGabrielli: No, I checked this with 400 X 700. It's working there also. The issue was with the properties. I'll once again check and update you

Comment: @MidhunMP I just solved the problem for your question, you asked why, with your code, you got the issue and I explained why. I think here is a 'different' solution.. ah it works for 400x700? and mine not?! I don't think so

Comment: @AlessandroGabrielli, I'm not trying to say your solution is incorrect. Your way of finding solutions seems to be hypothetical. And I can't find any wrong with my solution. Anyway I'll accept your suggestions and advices.

Comment: yes, sorry, I just thought that my solution fits better to his problem but, surely, yours solution have a lower computational complexity

Answer (score 1):

***TO CLEAR***
This is the code that you have to change to have a reusable code:

```
        c.moveTo(a/(can.clientWidth/can.width), b/(can.clientHeight/can.height));
        a = event.clientX - parentPosition.x;
        b = event.clientY - parentPosition.y;
        console.log('a:'+a+'--b:'+b);
        c.lineTo(a/(can.clientWidth/can.width), b/(can.clientHeight/can.height));
```

If you don't use this, the code below works only for 300x300 canvas size.
**LAST EDIT:**

By analyzing the 2d context (var c = can.getContext('2d');console.log(c);) you can easily understand this error: there is a relation (not explicit) from the canvas and it's 2d context.
As you can see from the image:
[image]
 the height and the width of the canvas(this is 500*500) are differents from its offset,scroll and client size. So, before to draw, you need to calculate the ratio: 500/150 will be the height coefficient and 500/300 the width one, so a will be multiplied by 1.66667 and b will be multiplied by 3.33333.

Same for the old example (canvas 300*300) the coefficent are 300/300=1 (a:width) 300/150=2 (b:height)
[image]

**OLD REPLY:**

But now, you have to guess why..cause actually I have no time

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var a = 0;
            var b = 0;
            function init()
            {
                var can = document.getElementById('can');
                can.addEventListener("click",click, false);
            }

            function click(event)
            {
                var can = document.getElementById('can');
                var c = can.getContext('2d');
                var parentPosition = getPosition(event.currentTarget);
                console.log(parentPosition);
                console.log(event);
                c.lineWidth = 1;
                c.strokeStyle = '#FFFFFF';
                c.beginPath();
                c.moveTo(a, b/2);
                a = event.clientX - parentPosition.x;
                b = event.clientY - parentPosition.y;
                console.log('a:'+a+'--b:'+b);
                c.lineTo(a, b/2); 
                c.stroke();
            }
            function getPosition(element)
            {
                var xPosition = 0;
                var yPosition = 0;

                while (element)
                {
                    xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollLeft + element.clientLeft);
                    yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollTop + element.clientTop);
                    element = element.offsetParent;
                }
                return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body oncopy='copy();' onpaste='paste();'onload ='init();'>
            <canvas id="can" style="height:300px;width:300px;background-color:black;">Oops!</canvas>
            <br>
            pagex<input type="text" id="ics">pagey<input type="text" id="ips"><br>
            screenx<input type="text" id="ics2">screeny<input type="text" id="ips2">
            <script>
            $("#can").mousemove(function(event) {
                var msg = "Handler for .mousemove() called at ";
                document.getElementById('ics').value= event.pageX 
                document.getElementById('ips').value= event.pageY;
                document.getElementById('ics2').value= event.screenX;
                document.getElementById('ips2').value= event.screenY;
            });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MidhunMP Eh..I tryed also different scripts on the web to draw but, each times, I get the same "double" error. The ratio difference between the real and the clicked points must have a reason. Maybe we are used the wrong coordinates

Comment: I think so, I'm googled on this issue but couldn't find a solution yet. Will update you if I get any result :) Anyway thanks :)

Comment: @MidhunMP Give me 2 mins and I'll post the answer

Comment: I got the actual issue. Please check the above answer :)